# python sequence order with optional values

Tags: python, sequence

Looking for some help generating some code to create all the possible sequences based on permanent and optional values.  Example...

The sequences are saved in a MySQL Db and the each value can be optional

So there is a sequence for example that returns the following order

1,2,3,4

1 & 2 are required 
3 & 4 are optional

So the outcome would return the following sequence possibilities:
[1,2], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3], [1,2,4]

Then I could compare a sequence to those to ensure the sequence received matches the order it should.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually only interested in the superset of the "optional" sequence. You can get your output by finding this superset and append each of its members to the "required" list.

```
from itertools import combinations

required = [1, 2]
optional = [3, 4]

superset_optional = [combinations(optional, i) for i in range(len(optional) + 1)]
for combinations in superset_optional:
    for comb in combinations :
        print(required + list(comb))

#  [1, 2]
#  [1, 2, 3]
#  [1, 2, 4]
#  [1, 2, 3, 4]
```